# Ready Player One - Book references in the film to 'Wargames'?

Tags: ready-player-one, ready-player-one-2018

Finally got around to watching the film version of '[Ready Player One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ready_Player_One_(film))'.

Obviously the film doesn't stick to the [book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ready_Player_One) when it comes to the tasks/tests but I did notice *references* to the main book themes:

- [Monty Python and the Holy Grail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Python_and_the_Holy_Grail) - Wade buys and uses a 'Holy Hand-Grenade'
- [2112 by Rush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2112_(song)) - Halliday has a 2112 poster on his wall and Aech is wearing a 2112 t-shirt
- [Tomb of Horrors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomb_of_Horrors) - The 'demon' logo from tomb of horrors is on the back of Aech's camper van

But, one of the main tasks is a recreation/acting of '[Wargames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarGames)' so is there a reference to it in the film ?

Comment: I initially intended to put an answer similar to what @FuzzyBoots did below, but then I thought you might be looking for more of an answer like even having a slight reference to something War Games included; like a luchbox, mini Whopper figurine, or anything... Those might be unavailable due to the rights as well, but who knows... is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Wait a second, isn't the holy grenade a reference to the "worms" videogame series?

Comment: @MatteoTassinari Worms was referencing Monty Python, with this weapon and elsewhere (for example many of the death quotes are taken from the Parrot Sketch).

Comment: Is there no noughts and crosses board stashed anywhere in the film?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to Ernest Cline, [no, and here's why](https://www.fandom.com/articles/ready-player-one-why-the-quests-have-been-changed-for-the-movie):

> Cline: “Some things had to change because we couldn’t get the rights. Like we had talked about getting *Blade Runner*. But because I think they were making the sequel at the time we weren’t able to get *Blade Runner*. So then we started to look at other 1980s films.
>
> “*War Games* also was unavailable. And also *War Games* was something that worked on the page, but also was more of a dialogue-driven movie and not necessarily a visually stunning movie. And we wanted a movie that was more visually striking.”